# Show dropdown values alphabetical order

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My dropdown values are showing alphabetical order. But i dont need like that. Because when I add values it is changing the alphabetical order.

For Example,

I have number of functions

1. -- Designer-- // Subfunction
2. Accessory Designer

..so on.

But My dropdown showing

1. Accessory Desinger,
2. --Desinger--.

My Jquery code here

```
 $('#dropdown').change(function () {
    $("#dropdown1").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Jobs/dropdown1",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'dropdownId': $(this).val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Success) {
                $('#dropdown1').children().remove();

                $.each(response.dropdown1, dropdown (index, role) {
                    $('#dropdown1').append(
                        '<option value="' + dropdown1.Id + '">' +
                            dropdown1.Name +
                        '</option>');
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        }
    });
});
```

when I click first dropdown, It is automatically show the second Dropdown.

Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: You forgot to post your jQuery code.

Comment: by any chance you using jQuery-UI?

Comment: you can sort on the Server side as well

Comment: I dont know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how to change the order on the server side, you must do it in the client.

From your description I gather the result is a `JSON` object with each item having `Id` and `Name`, and that you want to iterate them not by name, but by id.

Therefore I suggest the following change to your code:

```
if (response.Success) {
    $('#Roles').children().remove();

    var results = [];
    // Converting the JSON object into an array
    $.each(response.Roles, function(index, role) {
        results.push(role);
    });

    // Sorting the array items by Id
    results.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.Id - b.Id;
    });

    $.each(results, function (index, role) {
        $('#Roles').append(
            '<option value="' + role.Id + '">' +
                role.Name +
            '</option>');
    });
}
```

That should sort the resultset by `Id` before the items are added to `#Roles`.